# How to change just the time of the Date object in Java leaving the date information intact

Tags: java, date, datetime, date-conversion

I have a Date variable lets say deliveryDate. It's saved in MonngoDB in this format.

```
ISODate("2020-10-07T03:10:00Z")
```

Now I want to change the time property of delivery Date. But it has to be done based on some String which tells what time to be set. for eg **String time = "7:20 AM"** [ this time is based of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia ]. Then the result should be something like :

```
deliveryDate = ISODate("2020-10-07T11:20:00Z")
```

Some general note : 7:20 AM Monday, in Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia is 11:20 PM Sunday, Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

Now given the String time and Date delivery Date. How can I obtain the results above for all cases ?

The thing that I am expecting is :

```
public static Date adjustTimeOfDay(Date deliveryDate, String timeOfDay) {
    // Adjust the time of the day of deliveryDate on the basis of timeOfDay 
    // Keep the offset and zone same while adjusting
    return deliveryDate
}
```

Comment: How have you tried to do that? Can you show us your attempt?

Comment: Do you want to convert the given datetime to the time in Kuala Lumpur or do you want to manipulate the time of day by exchanging that part and leaving the time zone / offset as it is (UTC resp. `+00:00`)?

Comment: I want to leave the time zone / offset as it is. The time variable gives Kuala Lumpur Time.
I was trying to do something with instant. so basically deliveryDate.toInstant() and then work on extracting date and time. But on the internet there is lot of different time handling classes, LocalDate, Instant, Calendar, Date. etc. I am new to java. So kind of overwhelming for me. @deHaar

Comment: Is the `deliveryDate` a `java.util.Date`? `Instant` is a good choice while there are alternatives if you have a `String`.

Comment: yes its a java.util.Date @deHaar

Comment: I wouldn't use that at all, can you change to `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`? Would be easy to manipulate the time of day or zone afterwards.

Comment: Can you help me how to do that @deHaar

Comment: I can't help you with the mapping from MongoDB to Java, but I could help you with that conversion / manipulation. Unfortunately, you are expected to provide some code that you tried yourself. Just show what you have tried, no matter what the result was.

Comment: I dont want it to be mapped from MongoDB to java. I am working on changing the codebase. So in the Object there is this this property deliveryDate which is of java.util.Date. Now i need to create a method which takes in this.time and this.deliverydate and return the changed  this.deliveryDate.

Comment: @VishalAnand - 7:20 AM on 2020-10-07 in Kuala Lumpur will be 11:20 PM on 2020-10-06 at UTC. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes @ArvindKumarAvinash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the compatibility method `java.util.Date.toInstant()`, manipulate the time of day of that `Instant` which creates a different `Instant` and then convert back to a `Date` by `Date.from(Instant instant)`.

Here's an example method for the manipulation:

```java
public static Instant adjustTimeOfDay(Instant instant, String timeOfDay) {
    // convert the instant to an offset-aware datetime object
    OffsetDateTime deliveryOdt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    
    /*
     * provide a formatter that parses a time-of-day String.
     * PLEASE NOT that this formatter is not very lenient,
     * the String must be of the pattern "hh:mm a"
     */
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("hh")
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendPattern("mm")
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendPattern("a")
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .toFormatter();
    
    // parse that String to a LocalTime
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timeOfDay, dtf);
    
    /*
     * create a new OffsetDateTime
     * adding the new LocalTime to the old LocalDate at UTC
     */
    OffsetDateTime adjustedOdt = OffsetDateTime.of(deliveryOdt.toLocalDate(),
                                                                localTime,
                                                                ZoneOffset.UTC);
    
    return adjustedOdt.toInstant();
}
```

I used in a `main` like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * instead of creating a Date,
     * I directly use Instant here and parse your example String,
     * so just use your deliveryDate.toInstant()
     */
    String input = "2020-10-07T03:10:00Z";
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(input);
    // then take a time of day to be set
    String timeOfDayUpdate = "07:20 AM";
    Instant adjusted = adjustTimeOfDay(instant, timeOfDayUpdate);
    System.out.println(input + " ==> " + OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(adjusted, ZoneOffset.UTC)
                                                        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
}
```

which created the following output:

```
2020-10-07T03:10:00Z ==> 2020-10-07T07:20:00Z
```

## EDIT

You can rewrite that method to

```java
public static Date adjustTimeOfDay(Date date, String timeOfDay) {
    // convert the date to an instant and the instant to an offset-aware datetime object
    OffsetDateTime deliveryOdt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
    
    // provide a formatter that parses a time-of-day String 
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("hh")
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendPattern("mm")
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendPattern("a")
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .toFormatter();
    
    // parse that String to a LocalTime
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timeOfDay, dtf);
    
    /*
     * create a new OffsetDateTime
     * adding the new LocalTime to the old LocalDate at UTC
     */
    OffsetDateTime adjustedOdt = OffsetDateTime.of(deliveryOdt.toLocalDate(),
            localTime,
            ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // return a Date from the Instant you get out of the OffsetDateTime
    return Date.from(adjustedOdt.toInstant());
}
```

passing a `Date` and getting one returned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are almost what I needed but the only difference is I will be sending a java.util.Date instead of Instant and i needed the java.util.Date returned. I edited my question a bit to add a dummy method what I am expecting. Can you have a look at it @deHaar . Does sending the deliveryDate.toInstant() to adjustTimeOfDay and and converting the returned Instant by new Date(Instant) work? for my result?

Comment: Well, I described that in my answer text (not fully in the code comments), @VishalAnand . You basically take your `Date`, make it an `Instant` by `deliveryDate.toInstant()`, use my method and format it back using `Date.from(instant)`, **not `new Date(instant)`**.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you are looking for something like:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(adjustTimeOfDay("2020-10-07T03:10:00Z", "7:20 AM"));
    }

    public static String adjustTimeOfDay(String deliveryDate, String timeOfDay) {
        // Define the formatter to parse time like 7:20 AM
        DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                            .appendPattern("h:m a")
                                            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        return ZonedDateTime.parse(deliveryDate)
                .toLocalDate()
                .atTime(LocalTime.parse(timeOfDay, timeFormatter))
                .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"))
                .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")) + 'Z';

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-06T23:20:00Z
```

I recommend you use use `HH` for a time in 24-hour format. However, if you want to get a time string by ignoring `AM/PM`, you can use `hh` in the pattern given above and then you will get `2020-10-06T11:20:00Z` (but I do not recommend it as it will be confusing for anyone).

Comment: This is what I wanted to answer, but OP insisted on the use of `java.util.Date`, so using the legacy compatibility methods was what I thought nearest to an optimal answer. The example given in the question is misleading, because OP has a `Date` and wants to adjust its time of day. In general, this is a better answer ;-)

Comment: @deHaar - Sometimes your selflessness makes me think how big ❤️ you have got!

Comment: It's all for the future readers ;-) They should be able to see the solution OPs want and (better) alternatives.